# python simple data storage

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

I'm writing a little chatserver and client. There I got the idea to let users connect (nice :D) and when they want to protect their account by a password, they send `/password <PASS>` and the server will store the account information in a sqlite database file, so only users, who know the passphrase, are able to use the name.

But there's the problem: I totally forgot, that sqlite3 in python is not thread-safe :( And now its not working. Thanks to git I can undo all changes with the storage.

Does anyone have an idea how to store this stuff, so that they are persistent when stopping/starting the server?

Thanks.

Comment: you wouldn't store the actual password in the database though right - you would store a representation of the password (after hashing it with a salt etc)

Comment: of course! I use SHA-512, is it ok?

Comment: How about making sqlite thread safe?

Comment: You could try a different database? 
Something like mongoDB or redis could be a good place to start?

Comment: Looks interesting, but I need something simple and not a database server. Maybe I use a simple Json text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm using a simple JSON text file with automatic saving every minute